# Is there an HTML/Bootstrap way of setting element order in the navbar based on the toggle state of the responsive menu?

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to apply a responsive Bootstrap 4 navbar in Angular 8.

As long as the menu is closed, the order of the elements is as expected:
COMPANY, BROWSE, LOGIN

The problem:
As soon as I open the menu, the #menu gets the navbar-collapse flex attributes, as expected:

```css
.navbar-collapse {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    align-items: center;
}
```

**However, this pushes #company to the right because of the `flex-basis: 100%` and #login ends up below the entire menu.**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="company">COMPANY</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">BROWSE</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-nav" id="login">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">LOGIN</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I am having difficulties in making sure that #menu does not affect #company and #login. The only way I could think of was setting the order of the elements via bootstraps `order-*` class.
That requires me to know when #menu is open, which seems not possible without some programmatic jQuery observations (which I want to avoid).

How can I set the order based on the toggle state of #menu? 
Alternatively: How can I make sure that the elements stay where they are?

Answer (score 1):

in my case

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="about-us.html">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="../img/logo.png" alt=""/>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><i class="la la-bars"></i></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="menu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">BROWSE</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">LOGIN</a>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. The problem that I have though, is that in your case, the button is located in the middle. I want to keep the order that I mentioned above, with the button on the right side. Also: the LOGIN Field get's pushed below the menu when you open it, just like in my case.